# WordPress TwentyFourteen responsive theme resizing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am using a slightly modified version of the 2014 theme. It used to work perfectly on desktop and mobile handset - the design was responsive in the correct manner.

However, this past week, the website's suddenly started resizing incorrectly on mobile handsets. Instead of using up nearly full width for the main content, it keeps a gap of about 20-30% and shows the background image.

[I'm new here so it won't let me paste the image]

The site URL is http://pink.accuracast.com/

The really bizarre thing is that it seems to load this change after the CSS loads, which makes me think that it might be something in JavaScript that's causing such a resizing, but I can't for the life of me figure out what might be causing that.

I can't trouble shoot it as I normally would because the error doesn't replicate on a desktop browser when I resize it to a mobile screen size (though the other responsive features do kick in).

Could someone please look at the site and give me a suggestion as to what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I figured out the answer myself.

I had set a style for the Facebook Like & Share box as follows:

```
.fb_iframe_widget span {
    width: 90% !important;
}
```

As a result, it was forcing the window width and resizing the content area. I've now changed this under an @media style specification, and that's taken care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a mobile emulator?

Testing it this way may allow you to use your usual trouble shooting techniques to find the problem.

I do not see the problem you are referring to on this iphone 5: http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/#u=http://pink.accuracast.com/

Which mobile handset is giving you the issue?

Comment: I've seen the problem on my Nexus 5 (Chrome) as well as on iPhone 5 and 5s (Safari & Chrome)

The emulator is showing the results just as my desktop browser does when resized. However, something is changing when you see it on an actual phone

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that if you add

```
body {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

to your custom CSS it will fix the issue.

Hope this helps!